# reutilizar rutas para diferentes roles

Tags: laravel-5, rutas, users-roles

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación tipo CRM en laravel 5.8 y se me plantea una duda muy tonta pero que será necesaria para definir el sistema de rutas que tantos quebraderos de cabeza me está trayendo.

Resulta que mi aplicación tiene 3 roles diferentes ('admin', 'coach', 'runner'). Por intentar no utilizar trescientas rutas diferentes, quiero, por ejemplo, utilizar la ruta '/users' tanto para el rol 'admin' como para el rol 'coach'.

Mi problema viene cuando quiero utilizar dos acciones diferentes que dependen del rol del usuario conectado. Si un administrador accede a '/user' cargará una acción con su respectiva vista y lo mismo pasará con un coach; otro controlador y su correspondiente vista. ¿Tenéis alguna recomendación para no tener que declarar trescientasmil rutas?

Comment: Puedes crear por ejemplo para `/user` una ruta de la forma `Route::get('/{rol}/user', function(){  /*Aqui adentro puedes segun el rol llamar a la accion de la controller indicada*/ });`

Comment: Es decir que solo tendrias 1 ruta por todos los diferentes roles que tengas en el sistema. No obstante puedo incluso recomendarte que crees una controller para este fin y te evitas el `function(){` clousure en la ruta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias crear una controller llamada GeneralController

```
class GeneralController extends Controller
{
    public function users($role)
    {
        // Conformas el arreglo con las llaves y el value para las rutas
        // 'nombre role' => 'nombre de la ruta' Asegurate que cuando tengas tus rutas creadas tengas el ->name('nombre de la ruta')
        $routes = [
            'admin' => 'admin_user',
            'guess' => 'guess_user',
        ];

        // Si el rol entrado en la url no existe lanza un error
        if(!in_array($role, array_keys($routes))) {
            throw new \Exception("Invalid role name (".$role.")");
        }

        // Sino redirecciono para la ruta correcta
        return response()->redirectToRoute($routes[$role]);
    }
}
```

Ahora en tu ruta para los usuarios seria algo como esto

```
Route::get('/{role}/users', 'GeneralController@users')
```